# After a PHP crash IIS 7.5 stops responding requests until the whole service is restarted

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, php5, fastcgi

I have a standard PHP5.3 install under w2k8r2/IIS7.5 (with and without WinCache as I've tried both options).

The events happens as follows:

1) I get an error on the Application event log that says:

```
Faulting application name: php-cgi.exe, version: 5.3.6.0, time stamp: 0x4d81eb28
Faulting module name: kernel32.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7baf9
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00011389
Faulting process id: 0xec4
Faulting application start time: 0x01cc436ab5451001
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
Report Id: 04e3bab2-af5e-11e0-addc-0048548eefef
```

2) I get a Warning on the System event log that says:

```
A process serving application pool 'xyz' exceeded time limits during shut down.
```

An then, the website that corresponds to that app-pool stops working until I restart the whole service. Recycling the app-pool or restarting the website is of no help.

The app pool is configured as follows:

```
<add name="xyz" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="">
    <recycling>
        <periodicRestart time="01:30:00">
            <schedule>
                <clear/>
            </schedule>
        </periodicRestart>
    </recycling>
</add>
```

It's not load related as it happens at any time during the day, twice a day.

Suggestions will be greatly appreciated :)